# in vb.net how do i get the position of an object in a scrollable panel

Tags: vb.net, scroll, panel

I have a panel and many smaller controls inside of it. I'm trying to find the position of each control after it has been scrolled off the screen. Basically I'm trying to find if a control is in the viewable area of the parent panel. So after an object gets scrolled off the top of the panel I would expect it's "top" value to be negative, but that doesn't seem to be the case. The top of the viewable window of the panel is not 0.

Comment: What code have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

The controls location comes from the location according to the panel. Take this for example:

```
Dim viewable as Boolean    

If Button1.Location.Y < Panel1.Height AndAlso Button1.Location.Y _
        + Button1.Height > 0 Then

        viewable = True
    Else
        viewable = False
    End If
```

In the example above I take the Y location of the button and compare it to the height of the panel. Remember the location of the button is the top left corner of the button.
Then to check if you scrolled passed the button completely, you have to add the buttons height to the location because, previously stated, the location is from the TOP left corner.

Comment: This example of course is for a vertical scroll. Use location.X, panel1.width and button1.width for horizontal

Answer (score 0):

The example below may work for you.
This example creates PictureBoxes inside the Panel as you click the Button.
PictureBox position is determined by Panel Scroll positions. (`PanelXoffset` and `PanelYoffset` , `XPos` and `YPos`)

```
Dim PicBoxCount As Short = 0

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click


    If PicBoxCount > 5 Then Exit Sub
    '
    ' New Picture Box Define
    Dim PicBoxNew As New PictureBox
    '
    ' Set Panel Property
    Panel1.Size = New Size(300, 350)
    Panel1.AutoScroll = True
    Panel1.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle
    '
    ' Panel Scroolbars offset determine
    Dim PanelXOffset = Panel1.AutoScrollPosition.X
    Dim PanelYOffset = Panel1.AutoScrollPosition.Y
    '
    ' Increase the number of PictureBox
    PicBoxCount += 1
    '
    ' Based on scrollbar state, set new position
    Dim XPos As Short = (50 * PicBoxCount) + PanelXOffset
    Dim YPos As Short = (120 * PicBoxCount) + PanelYOffset

    ' Create new Picture box
    Panel1.Controls.Add(PicBoxNew)
    PicBoxNew.Name = "PicBox_" & CStr(PicBoxCount)
    PicBoxNew.Width = 100
    PicBoxNew.Height = 100
    PicBoxNew.Location = New Point(XPos, YPos)
    PicBoxNew.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle


End Sub
```